# Can not ping Always On listener from outside primary node

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I just setup SQL Server 2012 (on Windows Server 2012) Always On feature and have a problem with connecting to SQL Server Listener from non-primary node (it works from primary node though).

Here is the scenario:

```
2 nodes in different subnets: 
   SQL1 10.0.2.11 (primary)
   SQL2 10.0.6.11 (secondary)
Listener:
  Name: SQLPROD1
  Port: 1433
  Subnets       IP address
  10.0.2.0/24   10.0.2.102
  10.0.6.0/24   10.0.6.102
```

I can connect to `SQLPROD1` in SSMS on primary node (either `SQL1` or `SQL2`) but can't connect (not even ping) `SQLPROD1` from secondary or from any other client in the network.

I checked firewall and it doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem. I can ping `SQL1` or `SQL2` from any client but can't ping `SQLPROD1`.

Beside this, everything else works in Always On. I can successfully fail-over and see databases on other node.

Comment: Are you sure that the hostname is resolving to the right IP address, or resolving at all?  That would be my first verification.

Comment: Have you verified the listener is configured for both subnets?

Comment: You using two different network segments, is there any route between them?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issues as this. Recreated the DNS entries for the two listeners and making sure "Allow any authenticated user to update DNS records with the same owner name" is checked. Believe the failover event caused issues with the listener not updating it's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue.  All I did was manually failover to secondary node and listener name became pingable again.  Since the name is only configured in SQL (and not DNS) it appears SQL lost track of the name for some reason but the failover corrected the problem.

Comment: SQL server registers the listener name in DNS and AD. The cluster machine account needs to have